# AWS RDS Proxy Connection from Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-rds-proxy

We are using Java Spring Boot 2.3 alongside Postgresql as our database.
For better availability, we want to implement Multi A-Z and RDS Proxy for Postgresql.
In `application.properties` file, we are using the following properties for normal connection to the database and all works fine

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://zzzz.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=yyy
```

When using RDS Proxy, i am trying to use same properties, but instead of the DB URL, i am using the endpoint of the RDS Proxy

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://rds-proxy-endpoint.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=yyy
```

For testing purposes, RDS Proxy Security group is open and my machine has access to it, but still it wont let me connect, here is the error

```
24832 [task-1] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool  --- HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization. 
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
```

Am i missing something?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Your `Spring Boot` is running on an instance in same vpc as your rds proxy is using?

Comment: yes it is, but i want to test it on my local machine as well. Does rds proxy make sense if they are in same VPC? My use case is because i want to have instance in other AZ and in case of failure RDS proxy would help for faster DNS switch

Comment: rds proxy can't be accessed from outside of vpc. To access it from your local machine you would have to setup vpn or ssh tunnel or some other proxy, to access rds proxy.

Comment: If you have enabled VPC Flow Logs, then you can trace vpc flow logs to check, which aws resource is rejecting the network traffic. For VPC flow logs information please refer   https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/vpc-flow-logs-log-and-view-network-traffic-flows/ document from AWS.